# Can't login to Xfce4 session (login loop)

Tags: gnome, xfce

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. I installed the Xfce4 desktop (`sudo apt install xfce4`) to use it by remote desktop (it works faster). I have a problem with logging in to the Xfce4 desktop. When I first login to the Gnome dekstop, and than I want to switch to the Xfce4 desktop, the process gets stuck at the login screen. I can only login to the Xfce4 desktop after rebooting, and if I hadn't logged in to Gnome before.  How can I solve this problem?